# Spacing after Section

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I have some `subsubsection`-titles that break the line and some that don't. The spacing after the title is different for those two cases. I am currently using so many packages and stuff (`titlsec` is one of them) and I tried to find a MWE that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\subsubsection,numberless}
      {\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}
      {}
      {0em}
      {\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright#1}}
      [] 
 \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{1.7ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Some long long long long text that should break the line}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection*{some other text}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this weird spacing may occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `\parbox[t]` which is unnecessary.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\subsubsection,numberless}
  {\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\raggedright}

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{1.7ex plus 2pt minus 1pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Some long long long long text that should break the line}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection*{some other text}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For numbered subsubsections, you might do something like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength\mylena
\setlength\mylena{1.3cm}

\titleformat{name=\subsubsection}[block]
 {\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}
 {}
 {0em}
 {\makebox[\mylena][l]{\thesubsubsection}%
  \raggedright\hangindent\mylena}

\titleformat{name=\subsubsection,numberless}[block]
  {\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\raggedright}

\makeatletter
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1.7ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Some long long long long text that should break the line}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection*{Some long long long long text that should break the line}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection{some other text}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works thank you. But for the numbered subsubsections (and also sections) I guess I need parbox for the align, how can I make the weird spacing disappear in this case?:

\newlength\mylena

\newlength\mylenb

\setlength\mylena{1.3cm}

\setlength\mylenb{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\mylena\relax}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
      {\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}
      {}
      {0em}
      {\PlaceNumber{\thesubsection}\parbox[t]{\mylenb}{\raggedright#1}}
      []

Comment: @Kathiieee The third argument is intended for the number. Please, read the manual for further details.

Comment: @Kathiieee I added a solution for numbered subsections

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you see "weird spacing" suspect `\lineskip` :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\showoutput
\showboxdepth6

\titleformat{name=\subsubsection,numberless}
      {\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}
      {}
      {0em}
      {\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright#1}}
      [] 
 \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{1.7ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Some long long long long text that should break the line}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection*{some other text}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The log shows:

```
......\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
```

By using a parbox[t] you lose information about the bottom baseline of the heading so TeX can not ensure correct baseline spacing and inserts its fallback `\lineskip`